# How to change python path in MacOS terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Today I updated python to version 3.10.0, and my terminal will not use that version. I have two paths for python, and I would like to switch the default path from "/opt/miniconda3/bin/python" to "/usr/bin/python"

This is the output of the commands "which python" "which -a python" and "python --version". The 3.9.5 version is in the "/opt/miniconda3/bin/python" path, and the updated(3.10.0, installed today) version is in "/usr/bin/python" path. [image]

I know there are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246962/how-to-change-the-default-python-path) on here and [other](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) [places](https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf), but I can't figure out how to apply the answers to my situation.

How can I switch the path to default to "/usr/bin/python"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply deactivate your Conda environment with

```
conda deactivate
```

Example:

```
(base) ➜  ~ which python
/Users/me/miniconda3/bin/python
(base) ➜  ~ conda deactivate
➜  ~ which python
/usr/bin/python
➜  ~
```